# AngularJS Resource Custom Action and URL

Tags: angularjs, rest, resources

I'm trying to make a POST request to a URL with the following format:

```
/questions/:questionId:/answers
```

I have a resource set up (notice the custom save URL):

```
angular.module('questions').factory('AnswersResource',
    ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('questions/:questionId/answers/:answerId', {
            answerId: '@_id'
        }, {
            save: {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'questions/:questionId/answers'
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

With a wrapper:

```
angular.module('questions').factory('Answers',
    ['AnswersResource',
    function(AnswersResource) {
        return {
            save: function(answer, questionId) {
                AnswersResource.save({questionId: questionId}, answer);
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

When I make a call to:

```
Answers.save($scope.answer, '123456');
```

I get a POST request to the server like this (notice the appended question mark):

```
POST /questions/123456/answers?
```

This throws off the routing on my back-end. Does anyone know why this question mark is appearing?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Restangular?

Comment: No, I was just using regular $resource. I hadn't heard of Restangular before but now that I've checked it out I'll definitely consider it for future projects.

Comment: I wonder why you have the answerId: '@_id' bit.

Answer (score 1):

Although I still don't know why the question mark was being appended, I managed to fix the problem by simply removing my custom URL. It turns out that the $save command is smart enough to know to post to: `/questions/123456/answers` even without specifying my own URL.